# How can we pre-populate contacts into Caldera forms via query params

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

Title says it all: How can we pre-populate contacts into Caldera forms via query params

Answer (score 4):

Michael McAndrew shared a WIP at

https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm/pull/85

- it does not yet include any ACL
- people have to remember to add a hidden contact id to the form
- a dedupe rule where contact id triggers a match (contact_id weight = 1, threshold = 1) is required